# How to make task for Chrome that will refresh, press button & attempt to find

Tags: google-chrome, automation, website

I'm trying to find a really good phone number and so I want to make a task for chrome that will:

1) Refresh the carrier's page

2) Press the 'Choose new number' button

3) Look for a phone number that has four or more of the same digits in a row

4) If it finds one, alert me to select it and finish the activation. If it doesn't find one go back to the start of the program.

Is this possible and if so is it easy to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This project can be done via web browser automation. To get started have a look at  tools like iMacros, AHK, Autoit, Kantu or Sikuli.

But your project is not trival. No matter what tool you use, in all cases it requires some scripting (if/then logic etc) to solve the "Look for a phone number that has four or more of the same digits in a row" part of your requirements. No tool can do this out of the box.